# How i can remove -u in sudo option string by ansible config

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible

I try configure ansible for become other user:

My ansible.cfg entries

```
sudo_flags=
ssh_args = -t -t
sudo_exe = sudo /bin/su
```

I can escalate privilege on remote host only one way (and this works in ssh session):

> sudo /bin/su anyuser -

Example playbook:

```
---
- hosts: anyhosts
  become: true
  become_user: anyuser


  tasks:
  - name: check becoming anyuser
    command: "ls -ltha"
```

When i run my simple playbook, in verbose log output i see *-u* option:

> > '"'"'sudo /bin/su  ***-u*** anyuser -

How i can disable/remove this **-u** option in playbook or ansible.cfg?

Answer (score 1):

You have told Ansible that `sudo` is `sudo /bin/su`, but as far as Ansible knows it's still using `sudo`, which supports `-u` argument.  If you want to use some other command for privilege escalation, consider setting [become_method](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#become-method).

However, it's not clear why you're not just using *sudo*, since you appear to have sudo privileges.  Possibly setting `sudo_exe = sudo sudo` would actually solve the problem, since the first `sudo` would get you root access (which appears to work just fine, based on your question), and then `root` would be able to run `sudo -u ...`, which should work just fine.

Comment: i agree, at last i discover in documentation note for this case:

`Methods cannot be chained. You cannot use sudo /bin/su - to become a user, you need to have privileges to run the command as that user in sudo or be able to su directly to it (the same for pbrun, pfexec or other supported methods).`